# Tensorflow Keras Error: Input to reshape is a tensor with X values, but the requested shape has Y [Op:Reshape]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensor, tf.keras

This error has been addressed here in numerous questions but it seems mine is different than all of them.

I am building a (quantum) convolutional neural network. In order to do that, I created a custom layer which acts as the (quantum) convolution and outputs 1 float for each image patch sent into it.

This is my test code for the (Q)CNN model:

```
stride = 2      # Length of stride in convolution operation
batch_size = 64 # Number of training samples used in each iteration

# QCNN (convolves the input image with many applications of the same quantum circuit)

def HybridModel(data):
    # Define the input layer
    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=list(data[0].shape), batch_size=batch_size, name='Input')

    # Extract image patches
    patches = tf.image.extract_patches(images=inputs, sizes=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, stride, stride, 1], rates=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID',  name='ExtractPatches') 
    print(1, patches)

    # Reshape patches (because otherwise I get an error about the shape)
    reshaped = tf.keras.layers.Reshape([-1], name='Reshape')(patches)
    print(2, reshaped)

    # Loop over the coordinates of the top-left pixel of 2x2 squares
    q_results = []
    n_rows = (image_height - 1) // stride + 1
    n_cols = (image_width - 1) // stride + 1

    for j in range(0, n_rows):
        for k in range(0, n_cols):
            # Process a squared 2x2 region of the image with a quantum circuit
            q_results.append(QuantumConv(reshaped[:, 4*(j*n_cols+k):4*(j*n_cols+k+1)]))
    print(3, len(q_results), q_results[0].shape)

    # Transpose & flatten the output from quantum convolution
    quantum_conv = tf.concat(q_results, axis=-1, name='Transpose&Flatten')
    print(4, quantum_conv)

    # Apply dense layer with 2 outputs and softmax activation
    outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax', name='Dense')(flatten)
    print(5, outputs)

    # Create the model
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name='QCCNN')

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', # stochastic gradient descent
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.run_eagerly = True

    return model

# Train hybrid model
h_model = HybridModel(train_images)
# print(h_model.summary())
with tf.device('/CPU:0'): # otherwise it gives the error "JIT compilation failed."
    h_history = h_model.fit(train_images, train_labels, validation_data=(test_images, test_labels), batch_size=batch_size, epochs=1, verbose=2)
```

The model compiles and returns its summary without problems. Here is the output of the `print` functions along the code:

```
1 KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(64, 9, 6, 4), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='tf.image.extract_patches_87/ExtractImagePatches:0', description="created by layer 'tf.image.extract_patches_87'")
2 KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(64, 216), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='Reshape/Reshape:0', description="created by layer 'Reshape'")
3 54 (64, 1)
4 KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(64, 54), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='tf.concat_6/concat:0', description="created by layer 'tf.concat_6'")
5 KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(64, 2), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='Dense/Softmax:0', description="created by layer 'Dense'")
```

The shapes of the tensors seem correct in theory. However, when I try to train it with real data, it gives the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[123], line 67
     64 # h_model = HybridModel(a)
     65 # print(h_model.summary())
     66 with tf.device('/CPU:0'):
---> 67     h_history = h_model.fit(train_images, train_labels, validation_data=(test_images, test_labels), batch_size=batch_size, epochs=1, verbose=2)
     68     # h_history = h_model.fit(a, train_labels, validation_data=(b, test_labels), batch_size=batch_size, epochs=1, verbose=2)

File c:\Users\bravo\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\qml\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File c:\Users\bravo\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\qml\lib\site-packages\pennylane\qnn\keras.py:388, in KerasLayer.call(self, inputs)
    386 if has_batch_dim:
    387     new_shape = tf.concat([batch_dims, tf.shape(results)[1:]], axis=0)
--> 388     results = tf.reshape(results, new_shape)
    390 return results

InvalidArgumentError: Exception encountered when calling layer "QuantumConv" "                 f"(type KerasLayer).

{{function_node __wrapped__Reshape_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} Input to reshape is a tensor with 4 values, but the requested shape has 64 [Op:Reshape]

Call arguments received by layer "QuantumConv" "                 f"(type KerasLayer):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(64, 4), dtype=float32)
```

"Input to reshape is a tensor with 4 values, but the requested shape has 64 [Op:Reshape]"

This makes it seem like I set the custom layer to receive 64 samples of 4 values but it is only receiving 1 sample of 4 values and assumes those values as the first dimension.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
patch_size = 4  # Assuming each patch has 4 elements
for j in range(0, n_rows):
    for k in range(0, n_cols):
        # Calculate the start and end indices for the patch
        start_idx = (j * n_cols + k) * patch_size
        end_idx = start_idx + patch_size

        # Extract the patch and process it
        patch = reshaped[:, start_idx:end_idx]
        q_results.append(QuantumConv(patch))

this  loop, start_idx and end_idx are calculated to extract the correct patch from reshaped for each position (j, k)
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the correction but that is not my problem. The code is only a rough sketch of the procedure. Even with that change, QuantumConv still throws the same error: `Input to reshape is a tensor with 4 values, but the requested shape has 64 [Op:Reshape] (...) inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(64, 4), dtype=float32)`